# Problem mapping docker volume using samba after docker upgrade on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, share, volume, docker-desktop

Since a couple of days I’m trying to find a solution. After upgrade of my docker desktop to version 2.2.0.5, the DockerNat network interface has gone. I understand it’s a feature of this new release, np. Though I cannot figure out how I can share my docker volume with the host system. In my setup I use a docker volume where I place all my project source code and build directories and expose it to the host machine using dperson/samba container. After the upgrade I cannot expose it any longer, because dperson assumes mounting to a separate ip address like 10.0.75.2, but in the new docker all exposures happen to the host ip address, where it presumably conflicts with Windows own samba server. The other option is to use NFS server and to mount it as a network drive in windows. I’m afraid though it will experience same kind of problem.

My work situation is as follows. I need a unix file system and an access to my files from Windows for development purpose. Before I was running my native Windows editors like Sublime Text or Microsoft VIsual Code to develop the code and a number of docker containers accessing those files via docker volume mechanism for builds and tests. The other option can be to install those editors directly into the docker containers, but that solution looks ugly and the gui performance via X-server ports for Windows is unsatisfactory.

Do you have some other ideas?